# Why Laravel Jobs console returns failed but email is sent

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs

I don't understand why my `php artisan queue:work` command in the console returns failed but the email is sent and only the 1st function call is being fired.

```
public function handle()
{
    //1st email
    $this->sendto_client($this->request,$this->totalprodprice,$this->quotationprice,$this->featitem,$this->quoteid);

    //2nd email
    $this->sendto_branches($this->request,$this->totalprodprice,$this->quotationprice,$this->featitem,$this->quoteid);
}
```

Here is my dispatch method:

```
$job1 = new SendQuoteEmail(collect($request),$totalprodprice,$quotationprice,$featitem,$quoteid,"client");
$this->dispatch($job1);
```

Here are some console log.

```
[2022-02-15 23:50:04][28] Processing: App\Jobs\SendQuoteEmail
[2022-02-15 23:50:08][28] Failed:     App\Jobs\SendQuoteEmail
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting job is failed even though mail is sent because the code that you have written after `Mail` triggering is throwing the exception

For **Example** lets consider the following `Job` Class

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class FailedJobWithPartialSuccessJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        //this will work

        logger()->info('My Log message before Exception');

        //Your other logic

        throw new \Exception("Message is Logged before the Exception but the job is failed", 1);

        //code below the exception won't work

        logger()->info('My Log message after Exception');
        
    }
}
```

After disptaching the Job `FailedJobWithPartialSuccessJob::dispatch()` like this and staring the worker here is my `cli` output

[image: cli-outout-job-processing]

And here is the log file contents

```
[2022-02-16 05:00:21] local.INFO: My Log message before Exception  
[2022-02-16 05:00:21] local.ERROR: Message is Logged before the Exception but the job is failed {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 1): Message is Logged before the Exception but the job is failed at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\serverinventory\\app\\Jobs\\FailedJobWithPartialSuccessJob.php:39)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\serverinventory\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod.php(36): App\\Jobs\\FailedJobWithPartialSuccessJob->handle()
"}
```

As you can see the part before the `Exception` is Executed even the job processing is failed

Comment: This saved me. thanks for the effort!

Comment: If the solution helped you kindly accept and upvote my answer